# bakeで追加されたプロパティーが内部で使われているものと一致しません（CakePHP4）

Tags: cakephp

英語版（下記）に投稿した質問なのですが、うまく説明できてなかったのかもしれません。
分かる方いらっしゃいましたらご教授をお願いします。
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/117799800?noredirect=1
　
　
マイグレーションで「**foo_logs**」というテーブルを作成、「**FooLogs**」という名前でモデルとコントローラーをbakeしました。コントローラには「**$FooLogs**」というプロパティが追加されています（DOC内）。

bakeで生成された以下のコードでは、正常にデータが取得できました。
　`$fooLogs = $this->paginate($this->FooLogs);`
しかし、以下のように変更すると、例外「Call to a member function find () on null」となります。
　`$fooLogs = $this->paginate($this->FooLogs->find('all')->where($Conditions));`

デバッガで処理を追うと FooLogs ではなく「**Foologs**」でモデルクラスを特定しようとしていました（文字列として一致しない）。そのためモデルクラスを特定できずに、結局 $this->FooLogs は null のままとなり、例外が発生します。
bakeで生成されたコードの場合は、「FooLogs」で特定するようです。

find() 使用時にモデルクラスの特定に「Foologs」が使われるのには、何か理由があるのでしょうか。「log」というワードはCakePHPで特別な意味を持っているのでしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

*※解決したので回答を差し替えます。*

原因は、当該コントローラーのページへのリンク出力で、以下のように。コントローラー名を「foologs」としていたためでした。モデルクラスの解決の際、頭文字だけは大文字になるようです（foologs → Foologs）。
`$this->Html->link('○○○○', ['controller'=>'foologs'])`

凡ミスというやつですね。コントローラー名を正しく記述することで、問題なく動作することを確認しました。

お騒がせしました。

Answer (score 0):

とりあえず、対処方法を書いておきます。

$this->FooLogs を $this->Foologs に変更すれば動作はしますが、基本的に、bake 時に指定した名称（FooLogs）が使われるべきと考えます。
そこで、コントローラーの initialize() でモデルをロードします。これにより、bake 時に指定した名称を変更することなく、各メソッド内からアクセスできます。
　
　
※この投稿の主旨は「**find() において、なぜモデルクラスの特定に bake 時と異なる名称が使われることがあるのか、その理由を知りたい**」ですので、引き続き、識者の皆さんのご意見をお待ちしたいと思います。